# How to calculate the infimum and supremum of a sequence

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm really confused about the concept of infimum and supremum, basicly in order to find infimum and supremum I just start with $n=1$, look at what I get and then I put $n=2$ and look at it too, then I conclude what will be the infimum and supremum.

The problem with that method is that it may be hard when the expression is too complicated and I dont 'formaly' prove the infimum and supremum.

Other concept that drives me crazy is that $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ I dont understand why it differs from the limit of the sequence itself and how to calculate it.

It would be great for some numerical examples and explanations
Thanks in advance

**tl;dr

A) What are the steps to calculate the inf/sup of a sequence?  for example this sequence $$a_n=(n^2)^{n-1}-n^3+e^n + 4\sqrt(n)$$
B) what does it mean lim inf and lim sup?**

Comment: Your notion of looking at $n=1$, then $n=2$ isn't a catchall either. What if you have a set $A = \{0 \}$. What is $\inf(A)$ and $\sup(A)$ in that case? Or if you have a set $B = [0,1] \subset \Bbb{R}$, the idea of looking at the case of $n=1, n=2$ won't work in calculating $\inf([0,1])$ and  $\sup([0,1])$

Comment: For instance, $\liminf_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n=-1$ and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n =1$.

Comment: @Siminore But doesn't $inf(-1)^n = -1$ and $sup(-1)^n=1$ too? does saying lim make any difference?

Comment: Anyway, what you are asking is rather unclear.

Comment: @graydad All the examples in my book just say: "so we have the sequence $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ lets look at $minA=-1,maxA=\frac{1}{2}$..." it doesnt show how to get to there

Comment: @Siminore given a sequence $a_n=(n^2)^{n-1}-n^3+e^n + 4\sqrt(n)$ what are the steps to calculate its inf sup?

Comment: There is no step at all. You must guess and try to prove your conjecture. And, most of the times, it is very hard or even impossible. That's why mathematicians use inequalities and estimates instead of computing maxima and minima.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a numerical sequence, 5 values can be of interest:

- **infimum**: minimum if is reached, otherwise infimum is the "minimum in the limit", i.e. the greatest lower bound. For instance $1/n$ does not have a minimum, and has infimum $0$
- **supremum** is the symmetrical of infimum.
- **limit**: does not always exist, value from which you can get arbitrarily close  from some point on. Formally there is a limit $l$ if for all $\epsilon>0$ there is an index $N$ such that after $N$, all your terms are at a distance less than $\epsilon$ from $l$.
- **lim inf**: minimum of limits of extracted sequences. For instance if you have $(-1)^n$, limits of extracted sequence are $-1$ and $1$, so the lim inf is $-1$ (in this case it is also the minimum). But if your sequence starts with $-2$ and then it is $(-1)^n$, the minimum and the lim inf are different.
- **lim sup**: symmetrical of lim inf.

Exercise: try to prove that when there is no minimum, then infimum=lim inf.

Comment: Thanks do you have an example for lim inf != infimum?

Comment: I already gave one...

Comment: Yea but it was words and my English isnt that good so I didnt understand that example which sequence starts with $-2$ and then it is $(-1)^n$?

Comment: If you take the sequence $u_n=(-1)^n$, and replace any term by $-2$ (say $u_8=-2$ for instance), then the minimum (and infimum) is $-2$ and the lim inf is $-1$.